# Microsoft Teams multi-tab personal app - About tab placed between two application tabs

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft365

I have a Teams personal app that has two custom tabs, and generally the MS rendered About tab is appended to the end of the tab bar.

This has been working fine, but today a customer has found that the About tab is being placed in between the two application tabs.

Can anyone explain why, or possible solutions to get the About tab back into last position?

Comment: Can you share the manifest of the app that you are uploading? Please remove important Id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have resolved itself, putting it down to temporary glitch.